# get sheetname from xlsx2csv linux command

Tags: excel, bash, csv

I want to extract text from the excel file so i used **xlsx2csv** command

the text extracted does not give me sheetname

I have used command as : 
    `/usr/bin/xlsx2csv #{excel_name}.xls >> #{excel_name}.txt`

Can we get sheetname from using xlsx2csv??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xlsx2csv -s 0 ${excel_name}.xlsx >> ${excel_name}.txt
```

From `man xlsx2csv`:

```
   -s SHEETID, --sheet=SHEETID
       Sheet to convert (0 for all sheets).
```

Comment: Could you please tell me for `xls2csv` i have read **man xls2csv** but not found any options to find sheet name

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :)